# Are there any downsides to marriage?

Tags: reigns

Occasionally in Reigns, you are given the option to marry a princess from a neighboring kingdom. In the short term, agreeing to a marriage has benefits for religion, popularity, military, and money.

Is there any reason to decline a marriage? Are there any hidden drawbacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can die if any of your bars become empty ***or*** full. As a result, if any of your bars are close to being filled, the bonuses from marriage can result in death.

Comment: Oh I'm so happy from my marriage *dies from it*